# Django rest framework ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Django rest framework [ModelSerializer](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#modelserializer)

How to use [ModelSerializer](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#modelserializer) with [User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/auth/).

I just tried [quickstart](http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart).

And it was good. But password is saved on the plain text.

```
$ pip freeze
Django==1.6
argparse==1.2.1
djangorestframework==2.3.9
wsgiref==0.1.2

$ curl -X post -d "username=lee&password=test" http://localhost:8081/users/
{"id": 4, "password": "test", "last_login": "2013-11-26T08:12:06.166Z", "is_superuser": false, "username": "lee", "first_name": "", "last_name": "", "email": "", "is_staff": false, "is_active": false, "date_joined": "2013-11-26T08:12:06.167Z", "groups": [], "user_permissions": []}

$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user=User.objects.get(username='lee')
>>> user.password
u'test'
>>>
```

Maybe [ModelSerializer](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#modelserializer) isn't use [set_password](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L234).

So... What should I do in order to use [set_password](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L234) in [ModelSerializer](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#modelserializer)?

---

[EDIT]

Thank you for your answering~!

BTW, I have a question.

I think your code is something wrong.

https://gist.github.com/meoooh/7659801#file-gistfile1-py-L17

User object is not created yet. But it call get_object in line 17.

So I think something is little bit awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a User ViewSet and provide a set_password action (s. [Marking extra methods for routing](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets#marking-extra-methods-for-routing)):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response
from myapp.serializers import UserSerializer, PasswordSerializer

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset that provides the standard actions
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @action()
    def set_password(self, request, pk=None):
        user = self.get_object()
        serializer = PasswordSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user.set_password(serializer.data['password'])
            user.save()
            return Response({'status': 'password set'})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Thank you! Please see a question again!